# Angular Pipe not returning array from nested ngFor

Tags: angular, pipe, ngfor

I have pure pipe to filter data I know its not recommended but in my case filter will only happens on url change in most case on page load. Here is the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'sortPipe'
})
export class SortPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
 listArr = []  
  transform(value: any[], args?: string): any[] {
  value.forEach((val, index) => {
    if (val.group.indexOf(args) > -1) {
     console.log(val); // this retuning object and not array
     listArr.push(val); // not allowed
    }
  });
  retune val ; //this is object not array
 });
 return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: try to change `value: any[]` to `value: Array<Any>`

Comment: Why are you returning `val` and not `listArr`?

Comment: Thanks guys, push throw error that val is not assignable. So can't return listArray

Comment: not letting me change to Array<Any> Error - Cannot find the name Any

Comment: use `any` with lower case

Comment: no error now but still didn't work here's how my params looks like 
transform(value: Array<any>, args?: string): any[] {}

Comment: I can see val return in console like this but fitering not working - { group:"01,03,02,11,12,15,16", label: "Title1", url:"KWZYUR6MJVFS"}  { group:"01,03,02", label: "Title2", url:"KWZYUU"}  { group:"01,12,15,16", label: "Title3", url:"KWZJVFS"}

Comment: I am guessing that in console I see an object and not array and that may be the reason but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it for some reason typescript was not letting me push value in array. Here is the answer for someone who has similar issue

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'listFilter'
})
export class ListFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 list = [];
 transform(value: any[], args?: string): any[] {
  this.list = [];
  if ( typeof value !== 'undefined' ) {
   value.forEach(val => {
    if (val.group.indexOf(args) > -1) {
      this.list.push(val);
    }
   });
   return this.list;
  }
 }
}
```